# Get all roles related to one user (ASP.NET)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have 3 tables. `Users`, `Roles` and `RolesToUsers`

Here is `User` model:

```
public partial class User
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public User()
    {
        this.UserToRoles = new HashSet<UserToRole>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<UserToRole> UserToRoles { get; set; }
}
```

Here is `Role` Model:

```
public partial class Role
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Role()
    {
        this.UserToRoles = new HashSet<UserToRole>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<UserToRole> UserToRoles { get; set; }
}
```

And here is `UserToRole` model:

```
public partial class UserToRole
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Role")]
    public Nullable<int> RoleId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public Nullable<int> UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

I need to show all Users and related to it Roles.

I write this repo method

```
public List<UserViewModel> GetUsers()
{
    var result = db.UserToRoles.Select(x=>new UserViewModel
    {
        UserName = x.User.Name,
        RoleName = x.Role.RoleName
    }).ToList();
    return result;        
}
```

It gets all fine, but if I show it on screen via js, for example I have Ronald user that have 2 roles and it shows as `Ronald - Admin` and `Ronald - User`.

I need  to show it like `Ronald - Admin,User`.

Here is how my js script looks now.

```
function GetUsers() {
    let url = "/Home/GetUsers";
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            var separator = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
                $('#taskresult3').append(separator + '<b>' + data[i].UserName + "-" + data[i].RoleName + '</b>');
                separator = ",";
            }
        }
    });
}
```

How I can fix problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should group the roles on the server with the user they're associated with. For example, a model like this:

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

Now make your query this:

```
public List<UserViewModel> GetUsers()
{
    var users = db.Users
        .Include(u => u.UserToRoles.Select(ur => ur.Role))
        .Select(u => new UserViewModel
        {
            UserName = u.Name,
            Roles = u.UserToRoles.Select(ur => ur.Role.Name)
        })
        .ToList();

    return users;
}
```

Now on the client you can loop over the data user by user, for example:

```
function GetUsers() {
    let url = "/Home/GetUsers";
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            var separator = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
                var userRow = data[i].UserName + " - " + data[i].Roles.join(", ");

                $('#taskresult3').append(separator + userRow);
                separator = ",";
            }
        }
});
```

Comment: In you repo method code, you have one trouble `u.Select ......` , User doesnt containt definition for Select

Comment: Oops, small typo, hard to get this right when you're typing into SO and not a proper IDE :)

Comment: Nope. Not works.

I tried like this
`var users = db.Users.Select(u => new UserViewModel
            {
                UserName = u.Name,
                Roles = u.UserToRoles.Select(ur => ur.Role.RoleName)
            }).ToList();`

But Now I not see RoleName, wit UserName all okay

Comment: I've added an `Include`, does that help?